# datagridview custom fill resize

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, resize

I have a DataGridView with a DataSource and I want the data to be displayed on the entire width of the control with the auto-computed width of each column. The exception is the first one which should always have 100px.

I handled the Size event, I set always the fist column to have 100px and it works, but only if I manually resize the grid.

Is there any way I can do this automatically, right after the DataSource was set?

I tried to invalidate the control, I set (again) the autofill (and not only) flags of the grid, but no luck. Did anyone managed to do a similar thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing the columns, there is a property called `AutoSizeMode`. Im wondering why you are trying to handle it yourself. Just set all columns except the first one to `AutoSizeMode = AllCells` and then give your first column the width of 100px. Should do it shouldnt it?

*Bonus: You can even set one of the columns to `Fill` in `AutoSizeMode`. Would look a bit better as your table is taking the full width.*

[image]

If I missed the point please correct me...

Comment: I know it might sound strange, but the requirement is like this ... to have the first column with a given width. To be fixed and no-resizeable.

Comment: But it worked! :) In design mode I had no columns. The grid-view was empty. I just added manually a column and set its width as in your example. When I ran the code, voila: the cell had the correct width! Thanks!